# how to authenticate resumable uploads from appEngine flexible,similar as SignedURL in golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage, app-engine-flexible

I got this code to get a signedURL:

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

//Don´t worry about the errors, I´m handling them
func CreatSignedURL(r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    acc, _ := appengine.ServiceAccount(ctx)
    filename := "fileName"
    bucket := "bucketName"
    expires := time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 2)
    url, _ := storage.SignedURL(bucket, filename, &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        GoogleAccessID: acc,
        SignBytes: func(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
            _, signedBytes, err2 := appengine.SignBytes(ctx, b)
            return signedBytes, err2
        },
        Method:  "PUT",
        Expires: expires,
    })
    return url, nil
}
```

But, I want to authenticate similar as the code above with resumable upload

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func ResumeUploadURL(nameBucket, nombreObjeto string) string {
    url := "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/" + nameBucket + "/o?uploadType=resumable&name=" + nombreObjeto
    client := &http.Client{}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, nil)              // URL-encoded payload
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=??????????") // What should I use instead?
    r.Header.Add("Content-Length", "0")

    resp, _ := client.Do(r)
    .....
}
```

But I need auth_token,where auth_token I need to get it like it´s described here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing But I would wanna avoid that becasue it seems pretty silly to me  to authenticate in that way if I can easy authenticate with signedURL and with resume upload can´t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wanted to avoid to use auth2 because there wasn´t a nice documentation, and after reading a lot documentation and tried many fails examples, I finally go it to work, these are the steps to make a the token Bearer for Resume upload with json api

1. Download JSON credential from console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

   1.1)Select "Creat Credentials"
   1.2)Select "Service account key"
   1.3)Select your account
   1.4) Select JSON->creat
   1.4)It will download a JSON with the information you need
2. Creat a oauth2/jwt tokenSource

   import (
       "context"
       "net/http"
       "golang.org/x/oauth2/jwt"
   )
       var config = &jwt.Config{
                   Email:        "someEmail@something.com",
                   PrivateKey:   []byte("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nbablablablablablabalabal\nbablablablablablabalabalas=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"),
                   PrivateKeyID: "somethingVeryPrivate",
                   Scopes:       []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"}, //you can change/add scopes if you want https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing
                   TokenURL:     "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
               }
               token, err := config.TokenSource(context.Background()).Token()//handle error

3)Now  you have the id to use, it is in method token.AccessToken

All the procces to get the url, I put it here: https://github.com/johnbalvin/google-cloud-go/blob/master/storage/resumableUpload.go